# Countdown timer that restarts every 10 seconds for 4 times in total

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a countdown timer that starts at 10 seconds and counts down every second until 0. Once that happens it should start again from 10 seconds and count down to 0. This should happen for 4 times in total. I also want to achieve this using a return in the method.

This is what I have tried, I am getting an undefined result in the console log and also am not sure if the retries should just be a for loop around this method

*Service file*

```
  //Countdown timer
  public countdownTimer(retries, timeLeft) {
     setInterval(() => {
      if(timeLeft > 0) {
        timeLeft--;
      } else {
        timeLeft = 10;
      }
    }, 1000);
    return timeLeft;
  }
```

Component where I will be using the method

```
console.log(this.timeUtils.countdownTimer(4, 10));
```

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current approach is that `setInterval` is asynchronous and `return timeLeft` is executed immediately, not waiting for the interval to finish. This is why you're seeing `undefined` in your console log. Additionally, your current implementation doesn't consider the `retries` parameter, which should control how many times the countdown repeats.

To achieve your desired functionality, you can use recursion and a combination of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. Here's an updated version of your method:

```js
// Service file

// Countdown timer
public countdownTimer(retries, timeLeft) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const countdown = () => {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (timeLeft > 0) {
          console.log(timeLeft);
          timeLeft--;
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval);
          retries--;
          if (retries > 0) {
            timeLeft = 10;
            countdown();
          } else {
            resolve();
          }
        }
      }, 1000);
    };

    countdown();
  });
}

// Component where I will be using the method

this.timeUtils.countdownTimer(4, 10).then(() => {
  console.log('Countdown completed');
});
```

Explanation:

1. The `countdownTimer` method now returns a Promise, which resolves when all retries are completed.
2. The `countdown` function handles a single countdown from `timeLeft` to 0 and is called recursively for each retry.
3. `setInterval` is used to count down every second. When `timeLeft` reaches 0, it clears the interval and checks if there are more retries left.
4. If retries are left, it resets `timeLeft` to 10 and calls `countdown` again.
5. Once all retries are completed, the Promise is resolved, and you can handle the completion in the `.then()` method in your component.

This setup should provide the desired countdown behavior and allows you to handle the completion of the entire countdown process effectively.